# Testing gzip for users accessing website via forward proxy

Tags: nginx, gzip

An app of mine has nginx as a webserver, and I'm using `gzip` compression. I've checked gzip integrity via https://checkgzipcompression.com/ - it seems to be working A OK.

However, a lot of my users are accessing my website via a forward proxy. How can I test whether gzip is working correctly for those users as well? Please ask for more information as required.

---

In `nginx.conf`, some relevant lines are:

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable logging of gzip compression, example:

```
http {
    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

[...]

    server {
        gzip on;
        access_log /spool/logs/nginx-access.log compression;
```

This way you can see the compression ratio per IP, so just grep for forward proxy IP's and check the ratio.

Comment: I already have a directive for access logging `access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;` So I'll just need to customize my `log_format`, correct?

Comment: Yep, just add $gzip_ratio to your logging configuration, so you can see actually how much compression helps, and for which client ip